# Why can't change button width in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitableview

I have added a simple button to a tableview controller, I use grouped tableview cells so I want button to be the same width as cells.

[image]

For simplicity  I opened view options of button on IB, inspector.
I can change the height but width turns to 768 when I try to change it.

[image]

I dont wanna use `tableviewfooter` because I need button before and after any sections is generated. If I add button to view button does not stay beneath  table view rows.

How can I change the width of the button? Or another method to add button beneath all sections and cell of tableview that will also appear when there is no cells or sections?

Comment: Trying to understand the end result you are looking for.  Is it to have a button below the table view?  If so, then suggest you create a nominal `UIViewController` that manages a table view and a button.  It looks right now like a button has been added to a table view, which will result in strange behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete that button and drag and drop a `uiview` to same position. Once you have your `UIView` you should be able to add what `UIelements` inside of that `UIview`

[image]